# Is this a drill bit for concrete?

Tags: concrete, drill, hole

[image]

What kind of drill bit is this? Can it be used to drill a hole in concrete?

EDIT: after the accepted answer provided me with some details I found out what it is. Details [here](https://www.hikoki-powertools.nl/website/hitachi-powertools-nl/assets/files/catalogus-hikoki/Catalogus_Proline_2019_NL_HiKOKI.pdf), on page 5. And the answer is yes. It can be used on concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tell tail signs point to a masonry bit. The shape of the cutting teeth and the fluets on the shaft. That is certainly a masonry bit. Look like a design typically used on an SDS plus bit. If so, that's another determining factor.

Comment: It is and SDS+ drill bit (found out that's called after you mentioned it in your answer).   After a few searches I even found out the catalog details for it. It's a hikoki hammer drill bit, code 752755. And it can be used for concrete

Comment: Pretty much all SDS bits are explicitly for concrete. Some are built to cut rebar or wood as well but to my knowledge they are all primarily masonry bits.